# Rails.cache.read not returning new value when changed during request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, memcached

During a web request, I'm finding that subsequent calls to `Rails.cache.read` do not reflect the most recent value if modified during the request by another process (be it another web request or Rails console for example). I'm able to replicate the issue with a vanilla Rails app, using WEBrick, with the default `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore` as follows:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    logger = Logger.new Rails.root.join('output.log')
    logger.info Rails.cache.read('foo')
    sleep 5
    logger.info Rails.cache.read('foo')
  end

end
```

Let's say the starting value for the `foo` key is `alice`. During the 5 seconds of `sleep` here, if I run `Rails.cache.write 'foo', 'bob'` in Rails console, I'd expect the following logged:

```
I, [2019-08-22T18:05:04.551440 #48742]  INFO -- : alice
I, [2019-08-22T18:05:09.551971 #48742]  INFO -- : bob
```

But instead the result is:

```
I, [2019-08-22T18:05:04.551440 #48742]  INFO -- : alice
I, [2019-08-22T18:05:09.551971 #48742]  INFO -- : alice
```

Where it seems the call to replace the data for the `foo` key is not being recognised till I refresh the page. Note that this is only happening when ran as a web request, but not when the same code is called from console (called with `WelcomeController.new.index` for example).

In my actual project, I was hoping to make use of this approach to have a web request wait on the completion of another request based on a shared token - but have been stumped as to whether my expectations here are correct. In the project itself, puma is the webserver, DalliStore is the memory store, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be happening is that `ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore` prepends `Strategy::LocalCache` which in turn defines a rack middleware. This means that the file is only read once per rack request, and the value is stored in an in-memory cache. I do not see an easy way to avoid this, other than to somehow disable that middleware.